# How to unprotect and then protect a google spreadsheet from a user having view access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google-apps-script which run as user accessing the app.

[image]

Now this script uses google spreadsheet as database. My spreadsheet has view access to the group.

Now, I want to give edit access to the spreadsheet to the person running the script only for the moment when the script is run. Once the script is done the user access to edit the sheet should be revoked.

To achieve this I read the document provided by google [class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

and tried something like this :-

```
function Make_Roster(){
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOI');
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('LOB');
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 var protection = sheet1.protect().setDescription(me+"1");
 protection.addEditor(me);
 
 var list = sheet1.getRange(2,1,sheet1.getRange('A2').getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
 var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('roster');
 tmp.list = list;
 
  
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

But this not does not provide edit access to the user. Any advice how to achieve this goal.

To avoid confusion I have a web app which has a separate link:  `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxW/exec?v=home`

And a google spreadsheet link :`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KtxxxxxxxxxxxxxMc`

Now my web-app is shared with everyone and can execute as 'User accessing the web app'. My script in web-app access google sheet which is shared with the users as view access. But when other user try to run the web-app they are not able to retrieve or access the spreadsheet data.

Comment: In your case, who is the owner of the Spreadsheet?

Comment: I am the owner. but when I tested it for other it does not work they are not able to access the sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the owner of Spreadsheet is you. And you want to make users edit your Spreadsheet in the script by removing the sheet protect, and want to protect when the script is finished. How about my understanding?

Comment: Yes Tanaike that is exactly what I want.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. I think that when the Spreadsheet is shared with the user, the user can run the script. How about this? 2. In your script, the values are retrieved. But the Spreadsheet is not edited. How about this?

Comment: the script is not attached with the sheet. the script is a separate web app which has a different link. And the sheet is shared separately as view access. The user are not even able to retrieve the values from the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm confusing about your situation and goal now. I apologize for this. When you give me a time to understand about them, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike, I have edited my question. look at the end of my question. Let me know if this helps? else I will try some more.

Comment: Provide relevant web app code:js and html. Easiest way is to Execute as "me". It's also unclear why you need to provide editor access.  Your code does nothing to need this privilege

Comment: This script will be used by around 600 students. will Execute as 'me' not create problem on daily quota limit set by google and max 30 simultaneous execution?

Comment: Using protected ranges as a security measure is [not a good idea](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Since it's not possible to collect email addresses unless they manually write it down, I don't see a clear solution for this. Maybe using Drive's [feature](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:~:text=Click%20Share.,to%20give%20temporary%20permissions%20to.&text=Give%20temporary%20access.,to%20change%20the%20expiration%20date.)  to temporariy limit a user's access would help?

Comment: Ok. But why do you need to unprotect the sheet at all?

Comment: @TheMaster data is maintained in the sheet and i want to be intact and I don't want the students to temper with their records.

Comment: @Jescanellas its possible to collect email address as they accept the permission of my web app. For the matter of fact I was able to achieve this goal on previous version of my script. As I progress to code and upgraded version my code loose ability to do so.

Comment: If you have any solution I would be really thankful to you. this issue is my biggest challange.

Comment: I think a Form is the best way to achieve this. You can limit the submits to one per person, and append the data to the Sheet.